# Switching Matplotlib backends programmatically in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am running pyhton inside Spyder. My code produces static figures and an animated figure. For each type of figures, I need to use a different backend. How can I switch between them programmatically inside the code?
I am trying things like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
#Draw Static Plots
plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
#matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
#Draw Dynamic Plots
```

But I get different kinds of errors.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot switch the backend for `matplotlib.pyplot` on the fly. But you can do so for `matplotlib`.

You can change the backend of `matplotlib` by using this syntax:

```
matplotlib.use(gui, force=True)
```

Where `gui` is one of the following:

```
[
    'GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'GTK4Agg', 'GTK4Cairo', 
    'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'QtAgg', 'QtCairo', 'Qt5Agg', 
    'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 
    'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 
    'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template'
]
```

Else it will raise `ValueError`.

After changing the backend, to make it take effect on global scope, you have to rebind the name on the global scope.

You have several ways to do this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
plt = matplotlib.pyplot
```

Both the above will reassign `plt` in the current scope.

Since Python is scoped, assigning a variable in a function will only affect the function's namespace.

To make the change take effect in global namespace, there are many ways. Here are two simple ones:

```
global plt
plt = matplotlib.pyplot
```

```
globals()['plt'] = matplotlib.pyplot
```

I like the second option since it is more concise.

Putting it together:

```
import contextlib
import matplotlib

def switch_backend(gui):
    with contextlib.suppress(ValueError):
        matplotlib.use(gui, force=True)
    globals()['plt'] = matplotlib.pyplot
```

You can check the backend by `matplotlib.get_backend()`.

---

I had omitted something, if you see `ModuleNotFoundError` and `ImportError` that is because you haven't installed the corresponding libraries, `matplotlib` needs to import them to use them, it doesn't come with them and that is why they are called ***backend***.

You cannot use a backend without installing it first, you have to install it before trying to use it.

You very likely knew about this, considering your reputation level, but just in case you don't know, I wrote the above.

Answer (score 0):

Part of my problem with Spyder was that different figures by default were shown on top of each other in the same window when the graph window is separate from the main spyder window. The following solution worked for me. The figures are still stacked on top of each other but in separate windows so I can drag them apart! Not sure though if it is a good practice to import the matplotlib.pyplot twice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2

fig1 = plt.figure()
Draw static figure 1
fig2 = plt.figure()
Draw static figure 2
fig3 = plt.figure()
Draw static figure 3
…
plt.show()
plt2.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
Draw animated figure
plt2.show()
```